# c++ overloading operator<< to insert more objects

Tags: c++, io, overloading, operator-keyword

i am trying to overload operator<< to write my Class in a file but insert more lines at the same time ( more objects ).

```
friend void operator<<(ofstream& o,Departament&d)
{
    o<<d.denumire<< " " << d.nrAngajati << " ";
    for(int i = 0 ; i< d.nrAngajati-1; i++)
    {
        o<<d.efortOmOre[i]<<", ";
    }
    o<<d.efortOmOre[d.nrAngajati-1]<<"."<<endl;
}
```

And i can write in file with it but with just one object at the time.
Something like this.

```
Class a,b,c;
fisOut("out.txt");
fisOut<< a; fisOut<<b; fisOut<<c;
fisOut.close();
```

but what i really need to do its this:

```
fisOut<<a<<b<<c;
fisOut.close();
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Look it up again.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 3):

It is best practice to make the << operator return the stream itself. This allows to chain outputs like you desire.

So:

```
friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& o,Departament&d)
{
    ...
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Lol, that was so easy.. didn't seen that coming. Also thanks a lot !